# Not able to retrieve the data from json

Tags: arrays, json

```
[  
   {  
      "ID":264,
      "title":"8BDR \u2013 villa",
      "status":"publish",
      "type":"properties",
      "author":{  
         "ID":1,
         "username":"bm",
         "name":"bm",
         "first_name":"",
         "last_name":"",
         "nickname":"bm",
         "slug":"bm",
         "URL":"",
         "avatar":"http:\/\/0.gravatar.com\/avatar\/81ff187fd3ab62858b098258fb3f0479?s=96",
         "description":"",
         "registered":"2015-01-11T07:25:06+00:00",
         "meta":{  
            "links":{  
               "self":"http:\/\/titusandbindu.com\/bm\/wp-json\/users\/1",
               "archives":"http:\/\/titusandbindu.com\/bm\/wp-json\/users\/1\/posts"
            }
         }
      },
      "content":"",
      "parent":0,
      "link":"http:\/\/titusandbindu.com\/bm\/blog\/properties\/8bdr-villa\/",
      "date":"2015-03-18T08:32:24+00:00",
      "modified":"2015-03-18T08:52:04+00:00",
      "format":"standard",
      "slug":"8bdr-villa",
      "guid":"http:\/\/titusandbindu.com\/bm\/?post_type=properties&#038;p=264",
      "excerpt":null,
      "menu_order":0,
      "comment_status":"closed",
      "ping_status":"closed",
      "sticky":false,
      "date_tz":"UTC",
      "date_gmt":"2015-03-18T08:32:24+00:00",
      "modified_tz":"UTC",
      "modified_gmt":"2015-03-18T08:52:04+00:00",
      "meta":{  
         "links":{  
            "self":"http:\/\/titusandbindu.com\/bm\/wp-json\/posts\/264",
            "author":"http:\/\/titusandbindu.com\/bm\/wp-json\/users\/1",
            "collection":"http:\/\/titusandbindu.com\/bm\/wp-json\/posts",
            "replies":"http:\/\/titusandbindu.com\/bm\/wp-json\/posts\/264\/comments",
            "version-history":"http:\/\/titusandbindu.com\/bm\/wp-json\/posts\/264\/revisions"
         }
      },
      "_edit_lock":[  
         "1426668679:1"
      ],
      "_edit_last":[  
         "1"
      ],
      "_wp_trash_meta_status":[  
         "draft"
      ],
      "_wp_trash_meta_time":[  
         "1426668336"
      ],
      "_thumbnail_id":[  
         "267"
      ],
      "bm_property_owner_name":[  
         " AMMAR SAMI"
      ],
      "bm_property_owner_phone":[  
         "66610001"
      ],
      "bm_property_owner_email":[  
         "a.s.qambar@gmail.com"
      ],
      "bm_property_owner_address":[  
         "HIDD"
      ],
      "bm_property_category":[  
         "Villa"
      ],
      "bm_property_transaction_type":[  
         "BUY"
      ],
      "bm_property_price":[  
         "300,000"
      ],
      "bm_property_location":[  
         "HIDD"
      ],
      "bm_property_area":[  
         "350 Sqm"
      ],
      "bm_property_no_rooms":[  
         "8"
      ],
      "offer_shop_details":false,
      "featured_image":{  
         "ID":267,
         "title":"IMG_6948",
         "status":"inherit",
         "type":"attachment",
         "author":{  
            "ID":1,
            "username":"bm",
            "name":"bm",
            "first_name":"",
            "last_name":"",
            "nickname":"bm",
            "slug":"bm",
            "URL":"",
            "avatar":"http:\/\/0.gravatar.com\/avatar\/81ff187fd3ab62858b098258fb3f0479?s=96",
            "description":"",
            "registered":"2015-01-11T07:25:06+00:00",
            "meta":{  
               "links":{  
                  "self":"http:\/\/titusandbindu.com\/bm\/wp-json\/users\/1",
                  "archives":"http:\/\/titusandbindu.com\/bm\/wp-json\/users\/1\/posts"
               }
            }
         },
         "content":"<p class=\"attachment\"><a href='http:\/\/titusandbindu.com\/bm\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/03\/IMG_6948.jpg'><img width=\"250\" height=\"167\" src=\"http:\/\/titusandbindu.com\/bm\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/03\/IMG_6948-250x167.jpg\" class=\"attachment-medium\" alt=\"IMG_6948\" \/><\/a><\/p>\n",
         "parent":264,
         "link":"http:\/\/titusandbindu.com\/bm\/blog\/properties\/8bdr-villa\/img_6948\/",
         "date":"2015-03-18T08:51:18+00:00",
         "modified":"2015-03-18T08:51:18+00:00",
         "format":"standard",
         "slug":"img_6948",
         "guid":"http:\/\/titusandbindu.com\/bm\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/03\/IMG_6948.jpg",
         "excerpt":null,
         "menu_order":0,
         "comment_status":"open",
         "ping_status":"open",
         "sticky":false,
         "date_tz":"UTC",
         "date_gmt":"2015-03-18T08:51:18+00:00",
         "modified_tz":"UTC",
         "modified_gmt":"2015-03-18T08:51:18+00:00",
         "meta":{  
            "links":{  
               "self":"http:\/\/titusandbindu.com\/bm\/wp-json\/media\/267",
               "author":"http:\/\/titusandbindu.com\/bm\/wp-json\/users\/1",
               "collection":"http:\/\/titusandbindu.com\/bm\/wp-json\/media",
               "replies":"http:\/\/titusandbindu.com\/bm\/wp-json\/media\/267\/comments",
               "version-history":"http:\/\/titusandbindu.com\/bm\/wp-json\/media\/267\/revisions",
               "up":"http:\/\/titusandbindu.com\/bm\/wp-json\/media\/264"
            }
         },
         "_wp_attached_file":[  
            "2015\/03\/IMG_6948.jpg"
         ],
         "_wp_attachment_metadata":[  
            "a:5:{s:5:\"width\";i:1280;s:6:\"height\";i:853;s:4:\"file\";s:20:\"2015\/03\/IMG_6948.jpg\";s:5:\"sizes\";a:8:{s:9:\"thumbnail\";a:4:{s:4:\"file\";s:20:\"IMG_6948-150x150.jpg\";s:5:\"width\";i:150;s:6:\"height\";i:150;s:9:\"mime-type\";s:10:\"image\/jpeg\";}s:6:\"medium\";a:4:{s:4:\"file\";s:20:\"IMG_6948-250x167.jpg\";s:5:\"width\";i:250;s:6:\"height\";i:167;s:9:\"mime-type\";s:10:\"image\/jpeg\";}s:5:\"large\";a:4:{s:4:\"file\";s:20:\"IMG_6948-700x466.jpg\";s:5:\"width\";i:700;s:6:\"height\";i:466;s:9:\"mime-type\";s:10:\"image\/jpeg\";}s:5:\"small\";a:4:{s:4:\"file\";s:19:\"IMG_6948-120x80.jpg\";s:5:\"width\";i:120;s:6:\"height\";i:80;s:9:\"mime-type\";s:10:\"image\/jpeg\";}s:11:\"custom-size\";a:4:{s:4:\"file\";s:21:\"IMG_6948-1100x245.jpg\";s:5:\"width\";i:1100;s:6:\"height\";i:245;s:9:\"mime-type\";s:10:\"image\/jpeg\";}s:14:\"shop_thumbnail\";a:4:{s:4:\"file\";s:20:\"IMG_6948-180x180.jpg\";s:5:\"width\";i:180;s:6:\"height\";i:180;s:9:\"mime-type\";s:10:\"image\/jpeg\";}s:12:\"shop_catalog\";a:4:{s:4:\"file\";s:20:\"IMG_6948-300x300.jpg\";s:5:\"width\";i:300;s:6:\"height\";i:300;s:9:\"mime-type\";s:10:\"image\/jpeg\";}s:11:\"shop_single\";a:4:{s:4:\"file\";s:20:\"IMG_6948-600x600.jpg\";s:5:\"width\";i:600;s:6:\"height\";i:600;s:9:\"mime-type\";s:10:\"image\/jpeg\";}}s:10:\"image_meta\";a:11:{s:8:\"aperture\";i:0;s:6:\"credit\";s:0:\"\";s:6:\"camera\";s:0:\"\";s:7:\"caption\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"created_timestamp\";i:0;s:9:\"copyright\";s:0:\"\";s:12:\"focal_length\";i:0;s:3:\"iso\";i:0;s:13:\"shutter_speed\";i:0;s:5:\"title\";s:0:\"\";s:11:\"orientation\";i:1;}}"
         ],
         "offer_shop_details":false,
         "terms":[  

         ],
         "source":"http:\/\/titusandbindu.com\/bm\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/03\/IMG_6948.jpg",
         "is_image":true,
         "attachment_meta":{  
            "width":1280,
            "height":853,
            "file":"2015\/03\/IMG_6948.jpg",
            "sizes":{  
               "thumbnail":{  
                  "file":"IMG_6948-150x150.jpg",
                  "width":150,
                  "height":150,
                  "mime-type":"image\/jpeg",
                  "url":"http:\/\/titusandbindu.com\/bm\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/03\/IMG_6948-150x150.jpg"
               },
               "medium":{  
                  "file":"IMG_6948-250x167.jpg",
                  "width":250,
                  "height":167,
                  "mime-type":"image\/jpeg",
                  "url":"http:\/\/titusandbindu.com\/bm\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/03\/IMG_6948-250x167.jpg"
               },
               "large":{  
                  "file":"IMG_6948-700x466.jpg",
                  "width":700,
                  "height":466,
                  "mime-type":"image\/jpeg",
                  "url":"http:\/\/titusandbindu.com\/bm\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/03\/IMG_6948-700x466.jpg"
               },
               "small":{  
                  "file":"IMG_6948-120x80.jpg",
                  "width":120,
                  "height":80,
                  "mime-type":"image\/jpeg",
                  "url":"http:\/\/titusandbindu.com\/bm\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/03\/IMG_6948-120x80.jpg"
               },
               "custom-size":{  
                  "file":"IMG_6948-1100x245.jpg",
                  "width":1100,
                  "height":245,
                  "mime-type":"image\/jpeg",
                  "url":"http:\/\/titusandbindu.com\/bm\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/03\/IMG_6948-1100x245.jpg"
               },
               "shop_thumbnail":{  
                  "file":"IMG_6948-180x180.jpg",
                  "width":180,
                  "height":180,
                  "mime-type":"image\/jpeg",
                  "url":"http:\/\/titusandbindu.com\/bm\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/03\/IMG_6948-180x180.jpg"
               },
               "shop_catalog":{  
                  "file":"IMG_6948-300x300.jpg",
                  "width":300,
                  "height":300,
                  "mime-type":"image\/jpeg",
                  "url":"http:\/\/titusandbindu.com\/bm\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/03\/IMG_6948-300x300.jpg"
               },
               "shop_single":{  
                  "file":"IMG_6948-600x600.jpg",
                  "width":600,
                  "height":600,
                  "mime-type":"image\/jpeg",
                  "url":"http:\/\/titusandbindu.com\/bm\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/03\/IMG_6948-600x600.jpg"
               }
            },
            "image_meta":{  
               "aperture":0,
               "credit":"",
               "camera":"",
               "caption":"",
               "created_timestamp":0,
               "copyright":"",
               "focal_length":0,
               "iso":0,
               "shutter_speed":0,
               "title":"",
               "orientation":1
            }
         }
      },
      "terms":[  

      ]
   },
```

this is my array[0], json and like this i have array[1],array[3]. they have given the url directly going to the array of json no oblect specified or no key value given. how to access the data from hear below is my java code.

```
class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(Properties.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
        dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            //------------------>>
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("i");
                //int length = jarray.length();
                //System.out.println("length" + length);

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Properties_Property actor = new Properties_Property();

                     JSONObject author = object.getJSONObject("author");
                     String authorName = author.getString("name");

                     actor.setTitle(object.getString("name"));





                    //actor.getTitle(object.getString("_wp_trash_meta_status"));
                /** actor.setHeight(object.getString("height"));
                    actor.setDob(object.getString("dob"));
                    actor.setCountry(object.getString("country"));
                    actor.setName(object.getString("image"));**/

                    propertyList.add(actor);
                }
                return true;
            }

            //------------------>>

        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        dialog.cancel();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if(result == false)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your JSON data is in json array format. so 
change

```
JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("i");
```

to

```
JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(data);
```

Comment: JSONArray fullData = new JSONArray(FULL SOURCE BELOW);
int length = fullData.length();
for(int i = 0 ; i <length; i ++ { //Loop over the array and get individual element
JSONObject main = fullData.getJSONObject(i);
JSONObject author = main.getJSONObject("author");
//FROM Author then extract all the other details
String authorName = author.getString("name");
}
 "FULL SOURCE BELOW" what to specify in this place

Comment: JSONArray fullData = new JSONArray(FULL SOURCE BELOW);

Comment: In the place of FULL SOURCE BELOW there should be a String variable which holds JSON array retrived from response

Comment: in my json which i have given above. they have given only 2 array object a[0] and a[1] only there is no string variable. below is the link of json. please help me in this. http://titusandbindu.com/bm/wp-json/posts?type[]=properties

Comment: just replace your code (not whole) by my code and everything should work

Comment: its not working war. if i change it to JSONArray also

Comment: after doing so in my console it is giving a error after running like this error:sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

Comment: I need to see full logcat

Comment: thanks buddy i fixed the project. while calling the data i was passing object instead of array. thank you for helping